# iOS: How to programmatically add a view to a storyboard view

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cordova

Scenario: I am developing a hybrid Cordova (Phonegap) app for iOS. To mix native and Cordova code, I set up a storyboard in Xcode 7 where a UIView is embedded in a container view (using an embed segue), to be able to re-use the web view throughout the native app.

For the embedding of a Cordova view, I found these instructions:
http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/guide_platforms_ios_webview.md.html#iOS%20WebViews

which are basically saying that you have to call this:

```
CDVViewController* viewController = [CDVViewController new];
viewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
[myView addSubview:viewController.view];
```

but they do not explain how to add the view to a storyboard view. I am especially asking myself how to deal with the CGRectMake thing, as I want the view to render responsively, i.e. adjust itself to the parent view's constraints (instead of having a fixed rectangle).

I already implemented this by deriving from Cordova's standard app delegate, but this must have been the wrong way to do it. When I call Cordova's camera, take a picture and come back to my web view, the web view suddenly jumps out of it's borders (to the top of the window), and I see this error message in the Xcode console:

```
Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged
```

PS: I am actually using Swift, but I'm able to read Objective-C code, so a code sample in any of these languages is fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

Simply create an outlet for the view that exists in your storyboard, connect it and add the subview

```
@IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!

func addMySubview() {
 var viewController = CDVViewController()
 viewController.view.frame = containerView.frame
 containerView.addSubview(viewController.view)
}
```

Edit:
Here, I did an example in a playground so you can see how your view's frame changes with the parents. 
[image: Example]

Comment: Thanks for answering that quickly. Yes, this is part is clear so far. But how do I attach the right frame? I do not want to have a fixed CGRect size.

Comment: And sorry for using swift, but I imagine you understand.

Comment: BTW: I've also read somewhere that you have to call didMoveToParentViewController on the subview after adding it to it's parent, but this was not included in Cordova's documentation. Might this be causing problems?

Comment: You override didMoveToParentViewController if you need to do something after the subview is added or removed. 

From apple's docs:
"Your view controller can override this method when it wants to react to being added to a container."